# SQL Server : INSERT INTO from multiple tables without having any relationship between them

Tags: sql, sql-server

Table 1:

```
NAME      
------    
Clara
Bob
```

Table 2:

```
NUMBER    
--------
555-1111 
555-2222 
555-3333
```

and now I want to insert data in table 3 which shows me information like:

```
NAME    NUMBER
----------------    
Clara   555-1111
Clara   555-2222
Clara   555-3333
Bob     555-1111
Bob     555-2222
Bob     555-3333
```

I know this can be done using two different SQL queries, but I want to do this in single query. I don't have any relationship between table1 and table2. How can I insert these records in a single insert statement, without using `WHILE` loop.

Comment: I don't understand. How is the system supposed to know what the relationship is?

Comment: How do you get the desired data in table 3? Is it the cartesian product of the two tables? Joined randomly on rownumber?

Comment: Add one row to table 1, and adjust the result.

Comment: You mean to say just order of item should be consider as it is

Comment: I have updated the question

Comment: use cross apply

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `cross join` to generate the data:

```
select t1.name, t2.number
from t1 cross join t2;
```

You can use `insert` or `select into` to put the results into another table:

```
insert into t3(name, number)
    select t1.name, t2.number
    from t1 cross join t2;
```

Ironically, I can't think of a reasonable way of doing this with exactly two queries.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply try below query:

```
SELECT
    T1.Name,
    T2.Number
FROM @tbl1 AS T1,@tbl2 AS T2
Order BY T1.Name
```

Answer (score 0):

```
INSERT INTO table3(NAME, NUMBER)
SELECT table1.NAME, t2.NAME
FROM table1 FULL JOIN table2
```

Answer (score 0):

```
;With Cte1(NAME)
AS
(
SELECT  'Clara' Union all
SELECT  'Bob'  
)
,cte2 (NUMBER )
AS
(
SELECT '555-1111' UNION ALL 
SELECT '555-2222' UNION ALL
SELECT '555-3333' 
)
INSERT INTO Table3(NAME,NUMBER)
SELECT * FROM CTE1
CROSS JOIN CTE2
```